# Is is possible to get ES2015 module name in browser/node.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way in a ES2015 module to get the module name of the code is being executed at the current moment for browser/node.js? The only solution I found is

```
var curScriptElement = document.currentScript;
```

However, it can work only for browsers and I am not sure that it will work for ES2015 modules that were loaded by module loader as dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`import.meta.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) is the nearest thing you can get, although it's an URL.

<sup>(1) But it's still a proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta/#importmeta</sup>

<sup>(2) In Node, Chrome, Firefox, and many flavors, it's already there: you may already use it!</sup>

Comment: @Pavel_K It's used *as is*. You can access `import.meta.url` inside an ES module, and it contains a string representing the full URL to the current module file.

Comment: On the link you provided there is `Browser compatibility` according to which Chrome, FF, and Opera support it.

Comment: Browsers support it. Microsoft products don't.

Comment: @Pavel_K Right, I've just added that to the own answer. Node has it too, in fact, I'm already using `import.meta` in some project.

Comment: @Pavel_K No way. Double-check my answer: it's the nearest thing you can get... and it's still a proposal.